# Try to get a JSON from a URL

Tags: android, json, url

I am new here and I have a problem with my code and I don't know what is wrong with it because four month ago when i created the code it worked perfectly but know I want to continue the program and my code doesn't work any more.

So the purpose of my code is to get all the information for comics book painting in Brussels which are in JSON form and are from an Api given from the open data Brussels.

My code is divided in two class one asynch task and a class that is input stream operation:
Here is the url of the api i use : https://opendata.bruxelles.be/api/v2/catalog/datasets/bruxelles_parcours_bd/records?start=0&stop=52

first here is the model class:

```
package com.formation.appli.brusselscomicbookpaintingtourapp.models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by Jeremyvdm on 27/10/2017.
 */

public class ComicBookPainting implements Parcelable{
    String comicsPaintingTitle = "";
    String comicsPaintingAuthor = "";
    int comicsPaintingYear = 0;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lng = 0.0;
    String comicBookPaintingImageURL = "";

    public ComicBookPainting(){

    }

    public ComicBookPainting(String comicsPaintingTitle, String comicsPaintingAuthor, int comicsPaintingYear, double lat, double lng, String comicBookPaintingImageURL){
        this.comicsPaintingTitle = comicsPaintingTitle;
        this.comicsPaintingAuthor = comicsPaintingAuthor;
        this.comicsPaintingYear = comicsPaintingYear;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.comicBookPaintingImageURL = comicBookPaintingImageURL;
    }

    public String getComicsPaintingTitle() {
        return comicsPaintingTitle;
    }

    public void setComicsPaintingTitle(String comicsPaintingTitle) {
        this.comicsPaintingTitle = comicsPaintingTitle;
    }

    public String getComicsPaintingAuthor() {
        return comicsPaintingAuthor;
    }

    public void setComicsPaintingAuthor(String comicsPaintingAuthor) {
        this.comicsPaintingAuthor = comicsPaintingAuthor;
    }

    public int getComicsPaintingYear() {
        return comicsPaintingYear;
    }

    public void setComicsPaintingYear(int comicsPaintingYear) {
        this.comicsPaintingYear = comicsPaintingYear;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getComicBookPaintingImageURL() {
        return comicBookPaintingImageURL;
    }

    public void setComicBookPaintingImageURL(String comicBookPaintingImageURL) {
        this.comicBookPaintingImageURL = comicBookPaintingImageURL;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int i) {
        dest.writeString(comicsPaintingTitle);
        dest.writeString(comicsPaintingAuthor);
        dest.writeInt(comicsPaintingYear);
        dest.writeDouble(lat);
        dest.writeDouble(lng);
        dest.writeString(comicBookPaintingImageURL);
    }

    protected ComicBookPainting(Parcel in) {
        comicsPaintingTitle = in.readString();
        comicsPaintingAuthor = in.readString();
        comicsPaintingYear = in.readInt();
        lng = in.readDouble();
        lat = in.readDouble();
        comicBookPaintingImageURL = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<ComicBookPainting> CREATOR = new Creator<ComicBookPainting>() {
        @Override
        public ComicBookPainting createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ComicBookPainting(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ComicBookPainting[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ComicBookPainting[size];
        }
    };
}
```

here is my Asynch task :

```
    package com.formation.appli.brusselscomicbookpaintingtourapp.asynch;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.formation.appli.brusselscomicbookpaintingtourapp.models.ComicBookPainting;
import com.formation.appli.brusselscomicbookpaintingtourapp.tools.InputStreamOperations;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Jeremyvdm on 08/11/2017.
 */

public class GetTheComicBookPaintingFromJson extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<ComicBookPainting>> {
    // déclaration des variables
    private ArrayList<ComicBookPainting> completeListOfComicBookPainting;
    private int debut = 0;
    private int fin = 52;

    //region Callback
    public interface GetTheComicBookPaintingFromJsonCallBack {
        void listOfComicBookPainting( ArrayList<ComicBookPainting> completeListOfComicBookPainting);
    }

    private GetTheComicBookPaintingFromJsonCallBack callback;
    public void setCallback(GetTheComicBookPaintingFromJsonCallBack callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    //endregion

    // déclaration de l'url en partie sous forme de constante
    private static final String URLBASE_PARCOURT_BD = "http://opendata.bruxelles.be/api/v2/catalog/datasets/bruxelles_parcours_bd/records?";
    private static final String URL_PARCOURT_START = "start=";
    private static final String URL_PARCOURT_STOP = "stop=";
    //initalisation du callback
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ComicBookPainting> fresqueBDs) {
        if(callback!=null){
            callback.listOfComicBookPainting(completeListOfComicBookPainting);
        }
    }
    //récupération du parcourt sous forme de ArrayList<FresqueBD>
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ComicBookPainting> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        completeListOfComicBookPainting = new ArrayList<>();
        String brusselsComicsPaintingURL = URLBASE_PARCOURT_BD + URL_PARCOURT_START + debut + "&" + URL_PARCOURT_STOP + fin;
        Log.v("TEST_URI_API",brusselsComicsPaintingURL);
        JSONObject brusselsComicsPaintingJSON = resuqestJson(brusselsComicsPaintingURL);
        JSONArray brusselsComicsPaintingJSONArray = listOfComicBookPaintingJsonArray(brusselsComicsPaintingJSON);
        completeListOfComicBookPainting = convertJsorrayTolistOfComicBookPainting(brusselsComicsPaintingJSONArray);

        return completeListOfComicBookPainting;
    }
    // Transformation du Json en fresque bd
    private ComicBookPainting convertJsonToComicBookPainting(JSONObject jsonFresqueBD) {
        String title = "";
        String author = "";
        int year = 0;
        double lon =0;
        double lat = 0;
        String imageURL = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonField = jsonFresqueBD.getJSONObject("record").optJSONObject("fields");
            title = jsonField.getString("personnage_s");
            author = jsonField.getString("auteur_s");
            year = Integer.parseInt(jsonField.getString("year"));
            JSONObject jsonCoordonees = jsonField.getJSONObject("coordonnees_geographiques");
            lon = jsonCoordonees.getDouble("lon");
            lat = jsonCoordonees.getDouble("lat");
            JSONObject JsonPhoto = jsonField.getJSONObject("photo");
            imageURL = JsonPhoto.getString("url");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ComicBookPainting(title,author,year,lat,lon,imageURL);
    }
    // transformation du json objet en json array
    public JSONArray listOfComicBookPaintingJsonArray(JSONObject jsonComicBookPaintingArray){
        JSONArray listOfComicBookPaintingJsonArray = new JSONArray();
        try {

            listOfComicBookPaintingJsonArray = jsonComicBookPaintingArray.getJSONArray("records");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listOfComicBookPaintingJsonArray;
    }
    // Transformation du JsonArray en ArrayList<fresqueBD>
    public ArrayList<ComicBookPainting> convertJsorrayTolistOfComicBookPainting(JSONArray jsonArray){
        int lenghtParcourtJson = jsonArray.length();
        ArrayList<ComicBookPainting> completeListOfComicBookPaintings = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i < lenghtParcourtJson;i++) {
            String comicBookPaintingUrl = null;
            try {
                comicBookPaintingUrl = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("links").getJSONObject(0).getString("href");
                URL comicBookPaintingURL = new URL(comicBookPaintingUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) comicBookPaintingURL.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                JSONObject jsonFresqueBD = new JSONObject(InputStreamOperations.InputStreamToString(inputStream));
                ComicBookPainting comicBookPainting = convertJsonToComicBookPainting(jsonFresqueBD);
                completeListOfComicBookPaintings.add(comicBookPainting);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return completeListOfComicBookPaintings;
    }


    public JSONObject resuqestJson(String urlString){
        JSONObject json=null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            String result = InputStreamOperations.InputStreamToString(inputStream);

            json = new JSONObject(result);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        return json;

    }
}
```

and here is my final class the input stream operation (I think that the problem is in this file because the buffer reader is always nul and I know that my JSON work because i use the api for my iPhone app and it work perfectly):

```
package com.formation.appli.bruxellesparcourbd.tools;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by Jeremyvdm on 03/07/2017.
 */
//traite les String afin de les transformer en Json
public class InputStreamOperations {
    public static String InputStreamToString (InputStream in, int bufSize) {
        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        try {
            for (int ctr; (ctr = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                out.append(new String(buffer, 0, ctr));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot convert stream to string", e);
        }
        // On retourne la chaine contenant les donnees de l'InputStream
        return out.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param in : buffer with the php result
     * @return : the string corresponding to the buffer
     */
    public static String InputStreamToString (InputStream in) {
        // On appelle la methode precedente avec une taille de buffer par defaut
        return InputStreamToString(in, 1024);
    }

}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code I have try several thing but I really need your help.

thanks in advance for your time.

Best regards

Jeremy

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you may try use Retrofit2 with Gson to get json response from webservice, it's easier with less code.